# A real number $X$ is selected uniformally in the continuous interval $[0,10]$, find $P(2 \le X \le 5).$

Tags: probability

A real number $X$ is selected uniformally in the continuous interval $[0,10]$, find $P(2 \le  X \le 5).$

I'm not exactly sure how to interpret this, wouldn't I need some type of function to qualify the probability of this?

Comment: Isnt't the pdf  of $X$ given by $f(x) = 1/10$, $0 \le x \le 10$?

Comment: What's the pdf of $X$?

Comment: The probability density function.

Comment: Also the CDF for the uniform distribution is $\mathsf P(X\leq x)= \frac x{10}~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;10)}+~\mathbf 1_{x\in[10;\infty)}$

Comment: The book I'm reading hasn't PDF or CDG yet.

Comment: Then ... why are you given a problem requiring what you haven't covered?  That seems a little disorganised.

Comment: The probability is the area of the rectangle from $x=2$ and $x=5$ with height $y=1/10$. The reason is that the rectangle from $x=0$ to $x=10$ must have a constant (=uniformity) height such that the total area must be $1$. So $\Pr[2\le X\le 5]=3/10$.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't covered pdf, CDF, you can look at it this way:

$X$ is *uniformly* distributed on the interval $[0;10]$, so the probability that it lies within some *subinterval* is just a comparison of lengths.

$$\mathsf P(2\leq X\leq 5) ~=~ \dfrac{\Big\lvert[2;5]\Big\rvert}{\Big\lvert(0;10)\Big\rvert} ~=~ \dfrac{3}{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability density function for the continuous uniform distribution would be $f(x) = \frac{1}{10-0} = \frac{1}{10}$ for $x \in [0,10]$ and $0$ otherwise.

To calculate $P(2 \leq X \leq 5)$ you would integrate the pdf over $[2,5]$:

$$P(2 \leq X \leq 5) = \int_2^5 f(x) \; dx = \int_2^5 \frac{1}{10} \; dx = \left . \frac{1}{10}x \right |_2^5 = \frac{1}{10}5-\frac{1}{10} 2 = \frac{3}{10}$$